# Do I have to fix anything to move a model made in 2.7 to 2.8/2.9?

Tags: blend-files, conversion

If I wanted to use a model made in Blender 2.7, would I have to fix anything to make it compatible with 2.8 or 2.9?
(For example, Blender 2.8 removed the layers system, so would that have to be fixed?)

Comment: I like to open the Settings panel and untick "Load GUI" so I don't get the old GUI/Window layout, but that is a personal preference and not strictly a 2.7 -> 2.8/2.9 issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you don't need to do anything (unless you are using a third party addon). for example the layer system is now called collections, if you move from 2.79 to 2.80 or 2.90, the layers will switch itself to a collection system.